# Parametrising Intuition of Plane

Tags: scalar-fields

This might be a bit too "hand-wavy" for this forum but here it goes:

Generally the problem is this, I wish to create a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with some properties that I have "some notion" of inside of my head. Things like I want $f$ to:

- grow quadratically in "this" direction.
- decrease linearly in "this" direction.
- go towards 0 in this direction.

Sometimes capturing these ideas in a function is simple and sometimes it is not. So my question is this: what are some good methodologies for creating explicit equations for functions you picture in your head?

**EXAMPLE**

In paint I can draw the scalar field lines, or lines of constant potential energy, of an electric field I want the explicit formula of. To go from the explicit formulation of the scalar field to the electric field is [simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field#Uses_in_physics), the problem is the explicit formulation of the scalar field represented below for instance. How would you do it?

[image: Example scalar field that needs an explicit formulation. Lines of constant potential energy shown in varying shades of red.]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a good tool to have in the toolbox is the multiplication of the $\tanh$ function to terms which represent the behavior you want.

For example, when $m=n=1$ a function which grows linearly in the negative direction and grows quadratically in the positive direction can be written as:
$$
f(x) = \left(\tanh\left(x\right)+1\right)\cdot x^{2}+\left(-\tanh\left(x\right)+1\right)\cdot x
$$